# Div refuses to center

Tags: html, css

The problem should be able to be seen live at this link (on every page, as the main content of the page is contained by my "content" div): http://tucsonbagley.com/index.html

The "content" class (a container div) has a much larger margin on the left than on the right and, after going over my CSS ad nauseum, I just cannot figure out why. I've broken something for sure (it was working not long ago!), but I just can't figure out what.

If I remove my id Navbar or id Header divs, the Content div will default back to the left... yeah, at this point I'm lost.

The CSS in question:

```
.content{
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 68%;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

Example HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <p>Tucson Bagley</p>
    </div>

    <div id="socialmedia">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/BagelHero"><img src="images/Twitter_logo_blue.png"/></a>
            <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/tucsonbagley"><img src="images/linkedin.png"/></a>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/tucson.bagley"><img src="images/facebook.png"/></a>
    </div>

    <div id="header">
            <small>BagelHero@gmail.com</small>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html"><span>Gallery</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html"><span>Resume/CV</span></a></li>
            <li><span>Contact me</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="thumbleft"><h2>This is some content.</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin non varius metus. Pellentesque eu nunc tortor. Aliquam id lectus orci. Sed id consectetur eros. Curabitur semper nisl nibh, rhoncus lacinia nibh volutpat at. Pellentesque sollicitudin vitae ipsum ut dictum. Proin ac risus ac nisi interdum hendrerit. Pellentesque sodales mauris ac eleifend vehicula. Nulla convallis aliquet urna varius auctor. Donec eget ipsum ut mauris consequat auctor eget sit amet odio. Nullam sed lorem erat. Praesent consequat porttitor magna, sit amet feugiat odio tincidunt ut. Fusce congue eros vel quam condimentum, vel consectetur quam imperdiet. </p>
        </div>

    </br>

    <div id="copyright">
        <p>Copyright 2012-2014 | Tucson Bagley</p>
    </div>

</body>
```

Some help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `<div style="clear:both"></div>` before `.content` `div` and apply `display:block` to `.content` instead of `display:inline-block` and that's it

Answer (score 0):

change the css of your .content to look like this

```
.content{
    position: absolute;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:10px auto;
    width: 68%;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

the magic is the `left:0px` combined with `right:0px` and `margin:10px auto` which will only work in absolute mode.

**Edit** - updated css as per comments.

Comment: This method blocks several other aspects from view, parts of my navbar and copyright info. But thank you.